# Cheerio scraper won't find any links in a sitemap

Tags: cheerio, apify

I'm trying to fetch URLs from a sitemap (XML) that I want to scrape.
I tried using the standard Cheerio template for this but it keeps returning that no URLs are found.

Any idea why this happens?

```js
const Apify = require("apify");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

Apify.main(async () => {
  const input = await Apify.getInput();
  // Download sitemap
  const xml = await Apify.utils.requestAsBrowser({
    url: input?.url || "https://www.example.com/product-sitemap2.xml",
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": "curl/7.54.0",
    },
  });

  // Parse sitemap and create RequestList from it
  // const $ = cheerio.load(xml.toString());
  const $ = cheerio.load(xml);
  const sources = [];
  $("loc").each(function (val) {
    const url = $(this).text().trim();
    sources.push({
      url,
      headers: {
        // NOTE: Otherwise the target doesn't allow to download the page!
        "User-Agent": "curl/7.54.0",
      },
    });
  });
});
```

[image: Screenshot from my IDE].

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to use `xml.body` instead of `xml`.

[Docs for Apify.utils.requestAsBrowser function](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/2.3/api/utils#utilsrequestasbrowseroptions).

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(xml.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You trying outdated version, the latest is https://crawlee.dev/docs/examples/crawl-sitemap